# Different results when running the function multiple times - C

Tags: c, function, memory-leaks

I've written a function and when I'm running it once it works perfectly, but when I'm running it multiple times with different inputs something goes wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 20

int SumStr(char *str) {
  int i = 0, j = 0, num = 0, tempnum = 0;
  char temp[MAX_SIZE];
  while (*(str + i) != 0) { //While not NULL - Checked
    while (((*(str + i)) >= 48) && ((*(str + i)) <= 57)) { //while str[i] is [0-9]
        *(temp + j) = *(str + i);
        ++j; ++i;
    }
    if (j != 0) {
        tempnum = atoi(temp);
        num = tempnum + num;
        tempnum = 0;
        j = 0;
    }
    ++i;
}
return num;
}

void Test3(char *arr, int sum)
{

int tempSum = SumStr(arr);
if (tempSum != sum)
{
    printf("Your Output is %d, Expected: %d (-3)\n", tempSum, sum);
}
}

void main() {

Test3("ax3b5mt11f", 19);
Test3("5$5$5", 15);
Test3("1234", 1234);
Test3("1$0!100", 101);
Test3("1$1!1", 3);
}
```

The purpose of the function, is to sum all the numbers within the string.

When I'm running the function once with this main (for example), it works perfectly;

```
void main() {
Test3("1$0!100", 101);
}

Output: num=101
```

But when the main runs the function multiple times with different inputs, the output is completely wrong.

---

The output from this main;

```
void main() {
Test3("ax3b5mt11f", 19);
Test3("5$5$5", 15);
Test3("1234", 1234);
Test3("1$0!100", 101);
Test3("1$1!1", 3);
}
```

Is;

```
Your Output is 6871, Expected: 15
Your Output is 6718, Expected: 1234
Your Output is 5024, Expected: 101
```

Comment: Unless you are tasked with writing the most obfuscated code possible, `((*(str + i)) >= 48) && ((*(str + i)) <= 57)` really should be `(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')`

Comment: Or, better than an explicit range, use `isdigit()` from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: Actually, I'm being tested on using pointers, which is the reason why this code is written like that. Additionally, I can't use ctype.h, I can use only the libraries I've already mentioned in the code. Thanks!

Comment: No, the task doesn't force you to write such abominations. You can always add a temporary `char c = *(str + i);`. The comparison against magic numbers is inexcusable regardless of your task criteria.

Comment: @StoryTeller I totally agree that this code is awful. thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One issue is that  you do  not  terminate  your `temp`-string with a `'\0'`-character before passing it to `atoi`.
You could write:

```
temp[j] = '\0';  // or: *(temp + j) = '\0';
if (j != 0) { ...
```

Note that passing character sequence that is not correctly terminated with `'\0'` to a function that expects a (terminated) string yields undefined behaviour; that's probably what you observe then.

Second, if the last character of your input string is a digit, you increment `i` twice and thereby miss the string terminating character of  the input. This  again leads to undefined behaviour. To overcome this, you could check if  you are at the end of the string before  incrementing `i`:

```
    if (*(str + i) != 0) {
      ++i;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's a problem, but it doesn't matter for `atoi` most of the time. with this fix, I stil get 3 misses.

Comment: I've tried to NULL temp before passing it to atoi, but still getting 3 misses.

Comment: @LiorGingihashvili The relevance of proper termination fixing *this* problem is somewhat pointless to discuss. Failing to do so is plain wrong, and invokes undefined behavior if you do not terminate that string before invoking *any* function (standard library, or otherwise) that expects one. Even if it does *not* "fix" this problem, it should be fixed in itself, as it (a) eliminates undefined behavior, and (b) culls down the possibilities of what *is* contributing to your problem.

Comment: the main issue is the double increase of index. And of course you have to nul terminate.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: right; both lead to UB, so I simply deleted the "main"  from the issues.

Comment: @LiorG. Hope you're reading this answer and comments, as it covers the problem. Fyi, you can eliminate the `atoi` call as well if desired. [Something like this](https://ideone.com/PbNMm0). Regardless, this answer deserves selection; it covers both main problems in your code.

Comment: @StephanLechner This really helped me to understand and fix the issue, thank you so much. Thank you all for the advise as well!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to not terminating `temp[j]`, you also skip the terminating character in `str` by incrementing `i` both in the inner loop and outer loop.
When you skip the termination, it starts processing the next string [ or depending upon your compiler/OS, any old crap ].

btw,  `while (isdigit(str[i]))` is not only more readable, portable and efficient than yours, it also makes the comment unnecessary.

Comment: `isdigit` is indeed more readable; it is also in defined from `ctype.h`, which the OP has expressed they cannot use.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to congratulate [Lior Gingihashvili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7801699/lior-gingihashvili) on using the test code shown in the question.  That is, IMO, an excellent way of working.

This code doesn't attempt to fix the original code — that's already been done by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849885/15168).  This code shows a whole different way of approaching the problem. It uses a different set of library functions — [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) and [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) — and it avoids any copying of the source string (so it doesn't run into problems with null terminating strings).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static
int SumStr(const char *str)
{
    int sum = 0;
    str += strcspn(str, "0123456789");
    while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
    {
        /*
        ** Since *str is a digit, the value will not be negative and
        ** strtol() won't fail unless the value is too big for a long.
        ** Since we can't include <limits.h> (or <assert.h>, or
        ** <errno.h>), I plan to ignore overflow.
        */
        char *eon;
        long val = strtol(str, &eon, 10);
        sum += (int)val;
        str = eon + strcspn(eon, "0123456789");
    }
    return sum;
}

static
void Test3(char *arr, int sum)
{
    int tempSum = SumStr(arr);
    const char *pass_fail = (tempSum == sum) ? "**PASS**" : "!!FAIL!!";
    printf("%s Output: %5d, Expected: %5d, Data (%s)\n",
           pass_fail, tempSum, sum, arr);
}

int main(void)
{
    Test3("ax3b5mt11f", 19);
    Test3("5$5$5", 15);
    Test3("1234", 1234);
    Test3("1$0!100", 101);
    Test3("1$1!1", 3);
    Test3("x$.!-_+", 0);
    Test3("xxx1000y2345z3456=23412!", 30213);
    Test3("-0+0-0+0-", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, the code produces:

```
**PASS** Output:    19, Expected:    19, Data (ax3b5mt11f)
**PASS** Output:    15, Expected:    15, Data (5$5$5)
**PASS** Output:  1234, Expected:  1234, Data (1234)
**PASS** Output:   101, Expected:   101, Data (1$0!100)
**PASS** Output:     3, Expected:     3, Data (1$1!1)
**PASS** Output:     0, Expected:     0, Data (x$.!-_+)
**PASS** Output: 30213, Expected: 30213, Data (xxx1000y2345z3456=23412!)
**PASS** Output:     0, Expected:     0, Data (-0+0-0+0-)
```

(Yes: I did get `!!FAIL!!` lines when I had a bug in the code.)

Comment: I note that the code produces zero safely for an empty string — one where the first byte is a null byte.

Answer (score 0):

Correctly running program:

```
//Explanations in the commemnts

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 20

int SumStr(char *str) {
  int i = 0, j = 0, num = 0, tempnum = 0;
  char temp[MAX_SIZE];

  while (*(str + i) != 0) {
  //While not NULL - Checked

    while (  (( *(str + i)) >= '0') && ((*(str + i)) <= '9')  ) // more readable 
        { //while str[i] is [0-9]
            *(temp + j) = *(str + i);
            ++j;
            ++i;
        }

        if (j != 0) {

            *(temp + j) = 0; // termination of the string needed for atoi

            tempnum = atoi(temp);
            num = tempnum + num;

            tempnum = 0;
            j = 0;
        }

        // new:
        if (*(str + i) != 0) { 
            ++i;
        }
        else break; // detection of the end of string
    }


    return num;
}

void Test3(const char *arr, int sum)
{

    int tempSum = SumStr(arr);
    if (tempSum != sum)
    {
        printf("Your Output is %d, Expected: %d (-3)\n", tempSum, sum);
    }
}

void main() {

    Test3("ax3b5mt11f", 19);
    Test3("5$5$5", 15);
    Test3("1234", 1234);
    Test3("1$0!100", 101);
    Test3("1$1!1", 3);
    return 0;
}
```